# simple form and bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

With the most recent changes on Bootstrap, I'd like to apply common css class `input_html: {class: 'form-control'}` to all elements but without manually doing it for all. Is there any way to make it by default. I haven't found any setting for that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

jQuery could be a way of achieving this as Aaron Gong mentioned. It will save you the time of doing it manually but it actually adds an artificial step on the client side which may not be the cleanest solution.

You may also try with applying sass @extend (http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) using css selectors to select the type of input you want to modify.

Example

```
    input[type='email'], input[type='password'] {
      @extend .form-control;
    }
```

Comment: You're better off changing the default wrapper in simple_form_bootstrap.rb in app/config/initializers.

Answer (score 7):

You're better off changing the default wrapper in simple_form_bootstrap.rb in app/config/initializers.

E.g:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: :div, class: "form-group", error_class: "has-error" do |b|

    # Form extensions
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder

    # Form components
    b.use :label
    # b.wrapper tag: :div do |ba|
    b.use :input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block text-danger" }
    # end
  end

  config.form_class = "form-horizontal"
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (but * for all elements can incur some performance issue)

```
$('*').addClass('form-control');
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I use this gist to replace my simple_form_boostrap.rb in app/config/initializers.

[simple_form_bootstrap.rb Gist](https://gist.github.com/tokenvolt/6599141)

Answer (score 0):

Within the simple from initializer use:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.label_class = 'control-label'
  ...
end
```